# Android - intent match with Content Provider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

From reading the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) documentation, I see that it can be used for starting an Activity, Service or Sending a Broadcast.

I want to ask how Intents are related to Content Providers. I've use calendar and contacts content providers (following [Common Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html)), but those still use `startActivity`. I ask because the `PackageManager` has a API called queryIntentContentProviders, with the comment :

```
Retrieve all providers that can match the given intent.
```

I want to ask what are the use cases where an intent is matched against a Content Provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this was added as part of API level 19 (KitKat) my guess is that's is used with the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

> - The interaction starts when an application (in this example, a photo app) fires the intent `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.
>     The intent may include filters to further refine the criteria—for
>     example, "give me all openable files that have the 'image' MIME type."
> - Once the intent fires, the system picker goes to each registered provider and shows the user the matching content roots.

And the example content provider is defined like this:

```
    <provider
        android:name="com.example.android.storageprovider.MyCloudProvider"
        ...
        android:enabled="@bool/atLeastKitKat">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </provider>
```

This is the only example of Intent-to-Content-Provider matching that I've seen so far.

Actually, I don't think Content Providers could define intent-filters before, though I might be mistaken.

Comment: It seems very new, and isn't mentioned at too many places in the Intent documentation to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @Jake You're welcome. Actually, I hadn't seen it until you asked. :) But this explanation seems plausible, the storage access framework is probably calling it when it says that it "goes to each registered provider".

Comment: OK. I will check the documentation for Storage Access Framework.